# ERROR: Can't resolve all parameters for CustomTranslateLoader ... json import problem?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular9, ngx-translate

I'm using translate and I had to write my own loader because the default one was based on httpClient. My solution works, the project starts and languages ​​change. So everything works very well. Unfortunately, when I try to build `ng build my-lib --prod` I get an error. I guess it's related to json? (Angular 9).

**custom-loader.ts**

```
import { TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import * as en from '../../../lib-assets/i18n/en.json';
import * as pl from '../../../lib-assets/i18n/pl.json';

export class CustomTranslateLoader implements TranslateLoader {
  constructor(private availableLang: any = { en, pl }) {}
  getTranslation(lang: string): Observable<any> {
    return of(this.availableLang[lang].default);
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
"resolveJsonModule": true,
"esModuleInterop": true,
"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
```

**error after** `ng build my-lib --prod`**:**

```
ERROR: Can't resolve all parameters for CustomTranslateLoader in /Projects/my-app/projects/my-lib/src/lib/core/translate/custom-loader.ts: (?).

An unhandled exception occurred: Can't resolve all parameters for CustomTranslateLoader in /Projects/my-app/projects/my-lib/src/lib/core/translate/custom-loader.ts: (?).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of the initialization of the param **avilableLang** as Adya pointed out.

There are different set of rules for compiling against ***[`AOT`](https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler)*** and ***[`JIT`](https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler#choosing-a-compiler)***. So try to initialize the variable outside of constructor.

Answer (score 2):

It occurs because of this I guess :
constructor(private availableLang: any = { en, pl }) {}

If you want to provide availableLang = { en, pl } then initializing it in OnInit() life cycle hook is a better place.
We use constructor for dependency injection mainly. Try to implement this change.

Answer (score 2):

```
export class CustomTranslateLoader implements TranslateLoader {

  // original code doesn't have key in the object. you must have key in the object as shown below

  private availableLang: any = { en: en, pl: pl };          

  constructor() {}

  getTranslation(lang: string): Observable<any> {
    return of(this.availableLang[lang].default);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you did the below code in your app.module.ts

```
 TranslateModule.forRoot({
 
      loader: {
  
        provide: TranslateLoader,
  
        useClass: CustomTranslateLoader
  
  
      }
  
     })
```